# MySQL select b'1' returns integer 1 or ASCII character 1 depending on environment

Tags: php, mysql

On my home computer,

`mysql_fetch_row( mysql_query(" select b'1' ") )[0]`

returns string "1".

But when hosted on webserver it returns string having ASCII character 1.

Doc does say-

> Bit values are returned as binary values. To display them in printable
>   form, add 0 or use a conversion function such as BIN().

But on my local machine it still returns "1" without any conversion done by me.

How can I have the same behavior on my web server?

If I get the same behavior then I don't have to convert my PHP codes from like

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row( mysql_query(" select bit1_field from .. where .. ") );
if( $row[0] === '1' ) ...;
```

to

```
... select bit1_field+0 as bit1_field ...
```

where `bit1_field` is of type `bit(1)`.

Comment: Are you using the same version of PHP and MySQL both times?

Comment: @Patashu PHP and Apache versions are same. MySQL is different but the docs of both the versions say the same thing, that bits have to be converted to be displayed.

Comment: How are you testing ? Are you using `var_dump()` ? Also note that array dereferencing `mysql_fetch_row( mysql_query(" select b'1' ") )[0]` is only supported from PHP **5.4**. I hope you also enabled error reporting in case ...

Comment: When I saw that hosted code is behaving differently, I examined the returned values using Xdebug. I know, I'm using PHP 5.4.16. Error reporting is enabled on both the systems, but I think it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I'm not the only one who has observed this: 
http://gphemsley.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/php-mysql-and-the-bit-field-type/

Comment: My webserver is using MySQL 5.5 and on my local computer I've tested on 5.6 and 5.1; both the up and down versions are giving "1" through PHP. So maybe it's because of difference in php-mysql extension?

Comment: "A solution I found was to [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the binary data inside your mysql query to an integer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using two different drivers on the machines. There are two, `php5-mysqlnd` and `php5-mysql`. [Website Factor](http://www.websitefactors.co.uk/php/2013/04/mysql-libmysql-mysqlnd-and-bit-column-types-php54/) wrote about the different behavior for BIT field in late April and I have also several machines with same version, but different drives. I's probably because the driver is not changed when upgrading from an earlier version, but when php  >5.4 is installed, it gets installed with `php5-mysqlnd` by default. Here is the [MySQL page about the differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.library.choosing.html).

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I changed to mysqlnd on the server, now bit'1' is being returned as "1". yum remove php54-mysql; yum install php54-mysqlnd; service httpd restart;